# ARM GCC Linker flags to use external newlib libraries?

Tags: gcc, build, linker, arm, newlib

I have been trying to link separate libraries that I've built from newlib to a pre-built package of ARM GCC 12, which I got from their developer site. I've rebuilt newlib using modified flags gotten from the file in ARM GCC `12.2.mpacbti-rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi-manifest.txt`. Specifically I removed the `--enable-newlib-mb` flag as it causes a lot of extra build space to be generated. I have ran several builds of newlib and have verified that the newlib configuration flags being used do not affect the errors being produced.

Using the compilation flag *'-nostdlib'*, which from my knowledge is necessary to use external libraries instead of the default ones, results in some undefined references to C library functions. Some of these include *'memcpy'*, *'memset'* or *'malloc'*.

The current linker flags I've used for this are:
`-nostdlib -L[gcc path]/lib -lgcc -lc -lm`

With the built newlib libraries being located in the *[gcc-install]/lib* directory. This currently causes the undefined references.

Edit:
Compiler output contains undefined references to:
*'memset', 'mktime' 'setvbuf', 'strlen', 'strcmp', 'memcpy', 'strftime', '__aeabi_dcmplt', '__aeabi_f2d', '__aeabi_dadd', '__aeabi_dmul, '__aeabi_d2ulz', 'memmove', 'modf', 'localtime_r', 'mallinfo', '_ctype_', 'gettimeofday', '_errno', 'malloc', and 'write'.*

Comment: Try to pass the entire path to the `-L` option. Also, use the `--verbose` option to get useful debug information on where the linker is looking for the libraries.

Comment: Verbose helped me pinpoint that it is able to find the libraries. Providing the full path helped with that. However, GCC still can't seem to find the definitions for the standard functions. Shouldn't `libc.a` be providing those?

Comment: yes ,`libc.a` should provide the implementation of the C standard library. What functions cannot be found? Update the question with the log of the compiler if you need to.

Comment: Updated the post with more details about the issue. There are quite a few functions that GCC can't seem to find in newlib.

Comment: Are you sure you are linking the `-lc` _after_ your source file? Please post the `-v` output of the compile command and all options are you using. Please confirm that `libc.a` contains the symbol definitions. `'-nostdlib', which from my knowledge is necessary` I do not think `nostdlib` is the right choice. Try `--sysroot` or just `-L` or only `-nolibc`. With `nostdlib` you are also not linking with startup file.

Comment: `nostdlib` was causing the issue so you were right on the dime. Using just `-L` fixed linking issues. I found that the path I was providing was also pointing to the wrong `libc.a`, which was causing floating point ABI errors and is now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the flag `-nostdlib` caused linking errors due to the GCC not linking the startup file (as per KamilCuk's response). Omitting this flag and instead only using `-L` to provide the newlib library path solved the undefined function references.

Moreover, I had to spend some time resolving floating point ABI issues. The linker complained that my project's `.elf` file was using hardfp floating point ABI operations while my libraries were using softfp. I provided the following path for newlib, which solved the issue (version 4.3.0):

`-L[path to newlib build]/arm-none-eabi/thumb/autofp/v7/fpu/newlib -lc`